# Draw circles different color/size depending on a function's value

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I’m trying to draw circles with certain colors and sizes depending on the value of my functions. I'm working on this in Openframeworks.
My functions come from a json file in my bin/data folder, which is working well (I am able to fetch the values and write them on the canvas) and the code for them looks like this:

```
// Now parse the JSON
bool parsingSuccessful = result.open(file);

if (parsingSuccessful)
{
    ofLogNotice("ofApp::setup") << result.getRawString();

    // now write pretty print
    if (!result.save("example_output_pretty.json", true))
    {
        ofLogNotice("ofApp::setup") << "example_output_pretty.json written unsuccessfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        ofLogNotice("ofApp::setup") << "example_output_pretty.json written successfully.";
    }

    // now write without pretty print
    if (!result.save("example_output_fast.json", false))
    {
        ofLogNotice("ofApp::setup") << "example_output_pretty.json written unsuccessfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        ofLogNotice("ofApp::setup") << "example_output_pretty.json written successfully.";
    }

}
else
{
    ofLogError("ofApp::setup")  << "Failed to parse JSON" << endl;
}
```

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update(){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw(){

```
//    Making a definition for tonenames and drawing it on the canvas
ofSetColor(0);
myfont.drawString("Tone: ", 100, 100);
std::string tone_name = result["sentences_tone"][8]["tones"][0]["tone_name"].asString();
myfont.drawString(tone_name, 250, 100);




std::string joy = result["sentences_tone"][0]["tones"][0]["tone_name"].asString();

int sentence_id = result["sentences_tone"][sentence_id]["tones"][sentence_id].asInt();





std::stringstream ss;


ss << "tone_name      = " << result["sentences_tone"][0]["tones"][0]["tone_name"].asString() << std::endl;

ss << "score         = " << result["sentences_tone"][0]["tones"][0]["score"].asString() <<
std::endl;


ofDrawBitmapString(ss.str(), 50, 50);

//Making functions for the graphics

std::string tone_id = result["sentences_tone"][sentence_id]["tones"][sentence_id]["tone_id"].asString();

std::string score = result["sentences_tone"][sentence_id]["tones"][sentence_id]
    ["score"].asString();
```

So, for example if the tone_id has the value “joy” i want to draw a circle that is yellow and
the size would change depending on the score, the score can be whatever from 0-1,
so if the score is let's say 0.8 and tone_id is joy then that means the sentence is 80% joyful.

I am about to draw a lot of circles, about 100 (in 5 different colors) and i’m thinking of giving them a 50% transparency so they don’t overlap, how would i add that in this also?

btw. i’m using the tone analyzer api if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you currently struggling with?

Comment: "i’m thinking of giving them a 50% transparency so they don’t overlap" - you mean so they don't fully occlude eachother? - they may still overlap even if they are partially transparent - those two concepts are orthogonal. Also; where is your code?

Comment: I have made the functions tone_id and score by fetching data from my json file, they can have different values (depending on the sentence id, there are 86 sentences ids in my json file) and I am struggling with visualizing this data. I want to draw circles (this is openframeworks) depending on the json value that the tone_id and score function has.. I hope this makes sence, thanks a lot to everyone responding

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have updated this, sorry for the confusion. It's ok if they overlap a little bit but I would need some random positioning so they would not all just go in the same place

Comment: @TobiSH I have updated, sorry for the confusion.